# Is there some kind of Azure DevOps Work Item Tracker?

Tags: azure-devops, devops

Is there some kind of an app/widget which helps you track your work items? We have an issue when working on multiple projects, people keep forgetting to set work items as active and DevOps doesn't calculate hours spent on work correctly

Would be useful to see which of my work items are active or paused in one list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a method.

State paused for example.

First, set up a query and save it.

[image]

[image]

Second, go to the Dashboards of Overview.

[image]

[image]

[image]

After that, just share the Dashboards page to others and everybody of your team can easily know how many work items are in 'paused' state and everyone can easily click in to check what are the work items are in 'paused' state(Do not forget to click 'Done editing' at the end).

By this method, you can manage other states of workitems.